# Create new objects in R based on input file with information on these objects

Tags: r, assign

Assume I have the following lookup table:

```
object_lookup <- data.frame(name  = c(new_var_1, new_var_2, new_var_2),
                            value = c(7, "ABC", "XYZ"),
                            type  = c("numeric", "character", "character"))
```

I now want to go through that list and create the objects based on the `name` value, assign them the value based on the `value` column and want to make sure they have the type provided in `type`.

I know how I can create one new object at a time with `assign`, but I'm struggling with a) automating the process and b) making sure that the type is correct and c) how to deal with cases where more than one value is supposed to be assigned. I thought about some sort of apply function here?

Sth. like `apply(object_lookup, 1, function(x) {assign(name, value); if (type == "numeric) as.numeric(x)}`

Ultimately, I want to have two new R objects in that example:

```
new_var_1 <- c(7) # numeric
new_var_2 <- c("ABC", "XYZ") # character
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first column in `data.frame` should be character vector then you can try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

object_lookup %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value = list(value), type = unique(type)) %>%
  {if(any(count(., name)$n > 1)) stop("wrong input") else .} %>%
  mutate(value = map2(value, type, ~do.call(paste0("as.", .y), args = list(.x)))) %>%
  select(name, value) %>%
  pwalk(~assign(.x, .y, envir = globalenv()))
```

`stop` is there if input is wrong (same variable with different types)

Comment: Works like a charme. I could even simplify a bit by directly putting "as.numeric" or "as.character" in the onput file. Would help with not having to do the map2 part.

Answer (score 1):

May I recomend a slightly more verbose approach. There's nothing wrong with air and clarity in your code. It is clear what the program intends to do, it does in simple steps, and is easily and flexible to change for future new specifications.

Hope you are also ok with using a tibble instead of a data.frame. This has the benefit of not forcing your values to be characters, with the posisbly unwanted side effects that might have. (It'll be fine for characters and numeric, I don't know what else might go into this!)

```r
object_lookup <- tibble(
    name  = c("new_var_1", "new_var_2", "new_var_2"),
    value = list(7, "ABC", "XYZ"),
    type  = c("numeric", "character", "character")
)


known.types <- list(
    numeric = as.numeric,
    character = as.character
)

for( vname in unique( object_lookup$name ) ) {

    i <- object_lookup$name %in% vname
    vtype <- unique( object_lookup$type[i] )

    if( length( vtype ) > 1 ) {
        stop( "A variable can only have one type: '", vname, "' failed to process.")
    }

    assign(
        vname,
        known.types[[vtype]]( unlist( object_lookup$value[i], recursive=FALSE ) )
    )

}
```

When trusting and creating stuff from vairable input, it's advisable to have some failsafe mechanicms in place. The code above will for example never run unless the type exists in a list of declared types, which also provides a converter, which is a good security measure. You could just put `I` in there too if you don't need a converter, eg `weirdobject = I` in *known.types*.